# Git Rebase multiple times on same topic branch

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have a `Topic` branch which I continuous do development on it. From time to time I need to put the content back to `Main` Branch. I use `rebase` to do the merge for the first time (`T1` to `B` as shown in the picture). After that both `Topic` and `Main` branch continue to grow, at certain point `T2` I want to rebase again

[image]

Problem comes here, what I want is to apply commits between `T1` and `T2` one by one to `Main` Head, however, git still tries to apply commits between `T0` to `T2` to `Main` head. In another word, git are not aware of the fact that commits between `T0` and `T1` has already been rebased to `Main`. This is causing many unnecessary conflicts.

I read through the git rebase documentation, but seems there is not a parameter which can specify the starting point to calculate the `delta patches`. So I am stuck at this point.

Any one can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the answer after reading [rebase doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

```
git rebase --onto main T1 T2
```

It calculate the delta between [T1, T2] and apply them one by one to `main`.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up `merge` and `rebase`.

You have **merged** T0 .. T1 into the main branch, you have not rebased them onto the main branch. You should choose your strategy: rebase or merge always.

If you would have rebased T0..T1 on the main branch, your graph would have looked like this:

```
A main branch start
...
B <- main branch
T0'
...
T1' <- topic branch
```

That is: a linear history! Short recap:

- `merge` creates a single merge commit, history of each branch remains exactly as it was (as in your example)
- `rebase` rewrites the history of your (topic) branch. The result is a linear history.

Comment: Maybe my graph has caused some misunderstanding. `T1` to `B` is a `rebase`, I omit `T0'`, ... `T1'` to a single `B` for simplify the graph

Comment: I think this is my problem. I make "n" commits on my feature branch and then do "git rebase develop" before I create my PR. Then I make more commits, do a pull from develop to get the latest, and then run "git rebase develop" again. Am I correct in assuming that after every rebase that I should just create a new branch? Is that the safest way?

Comment: @fumeng you don't need to create a new branch. But each time you rebase, you have rewritten the history of that branch, so you need to force push (careful with that).

Comment: thank you. yeah, in vscode after the rebase says it's successful it doesn't prompt me to push my changes to the repo (as it might whenever i have other changes). so i guess that i'm leaving a fair bit behind when i don't force push.